# Proof Verification for Intersection of Sets in Functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

This proof comes from the theorem saying that if $f : A \to B$ where $E$ and $F$ are subsets of $A$, then $f(E \cap F) \subset f(E) \cap f(F)$. I'm proving the special case where $f$ is one-to-one. Could anyone verify this proof and let me know how to improve it?

> **Theorem** If $f : A \to B$ is one-to-one and $E$ and $F$ are subsets of $A$, then $f(E \cap F) = f(E) \cap f(F)$.
>
> **Proof** Suppose $y \in f(E) \cap f(F)$ and $f(x) = y$. Since $f$ is one-to-one, $y$ is uniquely determined by $x$. This means $x \in E$ and $x \in F$, or $x \in E \cap F$. Then $y=f(x) \in f(E \cap F)$ and $f(E) \cap f(F) \subset f(E \cap F)$.
>
> Now suppose $y \in f(E \cap F)$ and $f(x) = y$. Then $x \in E \cap F$ and $f$ maps $x$ to $f(E)$ and $f(F)$. Thus, the mapping $f(x) = y$ is such that $y \in f(E) \cap f(F)$ and $f(E \cap F) \subset f(E) \cap f(F)$.
>
> Thus, $f(E \cap F)$ and $f(E) \cap f(F)$ have the same elements and are equal. $\Box$

Comment: I think it works perfectly.

Comment: I think my wording would be more like: since $y \in f(E)$, there is some $x \in E$ such that $f(x) = y$.  Similarly, since $y \in f(F)$, there is some $x' \in F$ such that $f(x') = y$.  But since $f(x) = f(x') = y$ and $f$ is one-to-one, this implies $x = x'$.  Therefore, $x = x' \in F$ also, so $x \in E \cap F$, and $y = f(x) \in f(E \cap F)$.  (Makes it clearer why the proof fails if $f$ isn't one-to-one, for one thing.)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to be a little more careful when you use the fact that $f$ is one to one. You have a jump from $f(x)=y,$ $f$ is one to one, therefore $x\in E$ and $x\in F,$ or $x\in E\cap F,$ but you never establish why you can say that. Try this instead:

"Since $f(x)=y\in f(E)\cap f(F),$ then $y\in f(E)$ and $y\in f(F).$ By way of $f$ being one to one we have that there is a unique $x\in E,$ so that $f(x)=y,$ and similarly $x\in F$ so that $f(x)=y.$ Thus, $x\in E$ and $x\in F,$ so $x\in E\cap F.$"

You have to be a little more careful when you say $f$ maps $x$ to $f(E)$ and $f(F).$ You might way to say:

"Since $x\in E\cap F,$ then $x\in E,$ so $f(x)\in f(E),$ and $x\in F$ tells us that $f(x)\in f(F),$ so by way of $f$ being a function, $f(x)$ is unique, and so $f(x)\in f(E)\cap f(F).$"

Otherwise your proof is great. Double containment, $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$ $\iff A=B,$ is exactly how you want to show set equality.